# ReactJS conditionally combining 2 states in a loop

Tags: reactjs

im attempting to convert a vue project to a react based project and im facing the following problem. I wish to combine 2 different states together via a loop conditionally. Here is what my code looks like :

```
transitions:{
             {id : 1 , is_done : true , is_cancelled : false} ,
             {id : 2 , is_done : false , is_cancelled: false} 
                       }
state_class_mapping: {}

pending_state_class: {
         #bunch of styling
        },
        done_state_class: {
          #bunch of styling
        },
        cancelled_state_class: {
          #bunch of styling
        },
        current_state_class: {
         #bunch of styling
        }
```

Next , what i wish to do is to run through the transition state , and combine the styling with each transition based on the conditions : `is_done` and `is_cancelled`. The code below is an idea of what im trying to accomplish , but i know it would not work.

```
#in my code , transitions is taken from an api endpoint 

        var that = this;
        var newState = {}
        this.state.transition.forEach(transition => {
          if (transition.is_done) {
            #Code to "combine" the styling and the transition
          } else if (transition.is_cancelled) {
           #Code to "combine" the styling and the transition
          } else {
           #Code to "combine" the styling and the transition
          }
        })
         this.setState(state_class_mapping:newState);
    })
```

After which , i would use the `setState` to update the state_class_mapping

The end state should look  a little something like :

```
state_class_mapping: {
           {id : 1 , 
            is_done : true , 
            is_cancelled : false , 
            rect : xxxx ,  #extracted from the styling
            fill : xxxx ,
            } ,
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR;

Spread Operators to combine objects.

So, your transition state looks like this;

```
transitions = [
  {id : 1 , is_done : true , is_cancelled : false} ,
  {id : 2 , is_done : false , is_cancelled: false} 
]
```

And to combine with another state based on the transition what you could do is create a function that takes in `transition` and spit out new state like;

```
const giveMeNewState = (transition) => {
   if(transition.is_done){
     return { ...transition, 
       ...{
          newShinyState: true,
          somethingElse: true
       } 
     }
   }
   return { ...transition, ...{ defaultStyle: "abc" } };
}
```

And then later call the function to get the states.

EXTRA:

But in this case what I would like to do is create a map with key of state and value of style properties. like;

```
 const stateMap = { 
    "COMPLETE": {
       showShinyCompleteButton: true
    },
    "LOADING": {
       showLoadingSpinner: true
    }
 }
```

and then later setState using `stateMap[transition]` to return the state and avoid using jumble of if and else altogether. But its not always that you can avoid using if and else altogether.